# only the last part of txt file is readable of the if statement

Tags: php, html

My source code:

```
<?php

$x = 0;
$get = $_POST['suser'];
$lines = file("usernames.txt");

foreach ($lines as $name) {
    $x++;
}

for ($z = 0; $z < $x; $z++) {
    if ($lines[$z] == $get) {
        echo "Account is already taken!";
    }
}
?>
```

I have 3 accounts on my txt file, account1, account2, and account3.
when I put "account1" or "account2" on the text-box and submit it, the if statement didn't work but if I put "account3" on the text-box, the if statement works. it's just simply the last part of the txt file is readable by the `if` statement.

`$x` is the account counter. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line (except the last one, ie., account3) contains the trailing `\n` character that's why the `if` statement is returning `0` for account1 and account2 and not for account3. So, in order to read the lines without newline character, we use `file` function with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag.

```
<?php
$x= 0;
$get = $_POST['suser'];
$lines = file("usernames.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($lines as $name)
{
    $x++;
}
for($z = 0; $z < $x; $z++)
{    
    if($lines[$z] == $get)
    {
        echo "Account is already taken!";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks Man !